# Change of basis...

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

**Question:**Let $(1, z, z^2)$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $(1, z - 1, (z - 1)^2$ be another basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$. Find a matrix transformation from $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2$ to the polynomial $q(z) = b_0 + b_1(z - 1) + b_2(z - 1)^2$.

My idea so far is to expand $q$, *viz.*,

$$q(z) = (b_0 - b_1 + b_2) + (b_1 - 2b_2)z + b_2z^2.$$

Then, I get confused. My attempt was to look at a linear transformation $T$ from $p$ to $q$ by considering the action of $(1, z, z^2)$ on $T$, but this didn't get me anywhere.

My next attempt was to consider a change of basis matrix, but I am struggling on implementing the idea. Any help?

Comment: I think this is pretty straightforward. Why the construction of the action of $(1,z,z^2)$ got you nowhere?

Comment: You have a transformation from the basis B to the standard basis, and you know you can represent this as a matrix.  The inverse of that matrix will give you the transformation from the standard basis to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is confusing and poorly-worded. It asks,

> Find a matrix transformation from $p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2$ to the polynomial $q(z) = b_0 + b_1 (z - 1) + b_2(z - 1)^2$.

The problem is, what is the transformation? What do $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ have to do with each other? And what do their coefficients have to do with each other?

If we assume that $a_i = b_i$ for $i = 0, 1, 2$, then we get a perfectly valid transformation, but in finding a matrix for this transformation, which bases should we consider? If we consider from $(1, z, z^2)$ to $(1, z - 1, (z - 1)^2)$ (as one might guess), then the corresponding matrix is the identity!

I think the more likely guess is that $p(z)$ is supposed to equal $q(z)$, and that you were always supposed to compute a change-of-basis from $(1, z, z^2)$ to $(1, z - 1, (z-1)^2)$. This is confusing, given that the question asks for a transformation, mapping one polynomial to another. When finding the change of basis matrix, the underlying transformation is the identity transformation; it doesn't change the polynomial at all, just the coordinates used to represent it.

Anyway, assuming the latter guess is the correct interpretation, we compute the matrix for the identity transformation from $(1, z, z^2)$ to $(1, z - 1, (z - 1)^2)$. We first transform all the vectors in the first basis:
\begin{align*}
I(1) &= 1 \\
I(z) &= z \\
I(z^2) &= z^2.
\end{align*}
(No trick; applying the identity transformation is super easy!)

We then take these results and write them as (unique) linear combinations of $(1, z - 1, (z - 1)^2)$. This is the slightly trickier bit. We have:
\begin{align*}
I(1) &= 1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot (z - 1) + 0 \cdot (z - 1)^2 \\
I(z) &= z = 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot (z - 1) + 0 \cdot (z - 1)^2 \\
I(z^2) &= z^2 = 1 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot (z - 1) + 1 \cdot (z - 1)^2.
\end{align*}
Letting $B$ be the second basis, and reading off the coordinates, as column vectors, we have:
$$[I(1)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \quad [I(z)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \quad [I(z^2)]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, our change of basis matrix becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
And that's my best guess as to what the question wants. Hope it helps.